# Micronaut Maven Project Without the Micronaut Parent

Tags: java, maven, micronaut

I have a Java monorepo with a few child projects, each corresponding to a different service. I am trying to convert one of these from Dropwizard to Micronaut, while leaving the others using Dropwizard.

```
pom.xml
|--service1   <--- converting this, and only this, to Micronaut
|  `--pom.xml
|--service2
|  `--pom.xml
```

The top-level **pom.xml** contains common dependencies, plugins, etc. the child projectgs inherit via the `<parent>` mechanism. All of the Micronaut documentation, examples and project builder set the `micronaut-parent` artifact as the project's parent. I'm unable to figure out how to keep the existing inheritance while also getting all of the features from the micronaut-parent artifact.

Is there a way to have a Micronaut project without the inheritance, but with the features micronaut-parent provides? Is there some other workaround?

Comment: Import the pom into your dependencyManagement section. Same idea as with Spring, described here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-dependency-management-custom-parent

Answer (score 1):

Brute-force way of doing this is manually including the dependencies and plugins that are provided by the micronaut-parent artifact in your project's pom.xml file.

Also you should not forget to include the following to have plugins that are provided by micronaut-parent:

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
        <artifactId>micronaut-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>create-config</goal>
                    <goal>build</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

One last touch is to have a property micronaut.version in your pom that you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Micronaut -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-parent</artifactId>
            <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```